# how to use multiple tables in one jsp page

Tags: jsp, jdbc

i have to use two tables in one jsp page...one table is retrieving data from database and other one is inserting data into second table..
pls give any solution..it is not working..In first page there is a search button which takes you to next page i.e searchbid.jsp

**1st page**

***try.jsp***

```
<div class="form">
            <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/OA/searchbid.jsp.jsp">
               <input type="text" name="t1" placeholder="Search..">  <input type="submit" name="b1" value="Search" style="font-family: Pristina;
                                                                                       padding: 1px 12px;                                                                                           font-size: 17px;                                                                                           background-color: inherit;                                                                                           color: aliceblue;                                                                                          ">
            </form>    
        </div>
```

**2nd page-searchbid.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*;" %>
<%
try{
    HttpSession ss1=request.getSession();
                String ss3=(String)ss1.getAttribute("ss2");
    out.print("yes");
    String s1=request.getParameter("b1");
    if(s1.equals("Search")){
    String item=request.getParameter("t1");
    try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:oa");
    Statement smt=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=smt.executeQuery("select * from auction where iname='"+item+"'");
    while(rs.next()){
    String name=rs.getString("iname");
    String desc=rs.getString("description");
    String mp=rs.getString("m_p");
    String ae=rs.getString("A_e");``

   out.print("no");
     out.print("<br><img src='"+rs.getString("path")+"' width='200' height='200'>");
   out.print("<br>Name<br>");
  out.print("<input type='text' name='n1' value='"+name+"'>");

    %>
      Your Bid <input type="text" name="t2">
           <br><input type="submit" name="b2" value="Click">
<%

         String ap=request.getParameter("b2");
                          if (ap.equals("Click")) {
                                String ybid = request.getParameter("t2");

                                    smt.executeUpdate("insert into ebid(uid,pname,yourb)values('"+ss3+"','"+name+"',"+ybid+")");
                                    out.print("Thanks for Bidding");   }}}   
    catch(Exception t)
{
}    }
    }

       catch(Exception m)
{
}  
 %>
</form>
```

Comment: _it is not working_ is not valid here .post the errors you get

Comment: actually when I click on Click button,then it takes to same page..